# MySQL efficient lookup query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I need to combine to get the data I need, but the queries that give the desired result are all very expensive.

I have a products table (id, name) and a stock table (id, pid, supplier, stock, price). The stock.pid is the foreign key to products.id, but each product can have multiple suppliers and therefor multiple entries in the stock table.

What I need is for each product the cheapest price and current stock, combined with all data from the products record, ordered on prices ascending.

What I tried is (and several variations):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pid), MIN(price), stock, p.*
FROM stock s LEFT (INNER) JOIN
     product
     ON pid = s.id
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY price (LIMIT 100)
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest, but it runs in 1,3 seconds. About 1,0 seconds to slow

select s.pid, min(price), p.* from stock s, products p where p.pid = s.id group by s.pid order by price limit 100

Comment: Do an Explain on it. I expect it's the order by that's killing you, and everyone else as well. Not sure how much that could be done about though. Maybe an index on Stock by pid and price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um

```
Select products.*,stock.stock,cheapest.cheapestprice
From (select id,Min(Price) as cheapestPrice From Stock Group By id) cheapest
inner join Stock on stock.id = cheapest.id
inner join products on product.id = stock.pid
Order by cheapest.cheapestprice
```

maybe

Comment: This solution doesn't work, I added a from block into the subquery, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well discounting the daft head omission I've just fixed, in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Before it didn't give me any result at all. Now I tried again and it takes 0.1 second to execute.

select pid, min(price) from stock group by pid

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a sec, couldn't edit my comment...

First it didn't give me any result at all. Now I tried again and it takes 0.1 second to execute. But "select pid, min(price) from stock group by pid" only takes 0,0017sec. I need to get every tenth of a second off, so the difference between finding the stock records and "just" adding some extra fields when the id of each field is known shouldn't take that long (should it?)

(Your answer is dramatically faster then the 1,3 second my query needed, but I need to get it as fast as possible!)

Comment: If I were you I'd close this question (accepting my answer :) ) ask another using this query. In the question post the query plan, you can get that by just prefixing the query with Explain and executing it. Then ask how can I make this even faster. I suspect its the order by where the hit is, but can't say for definite.

Comment: I accepted yours as an answer to my orignal question. But I solved it differently as you can see in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this with a subquery:

```
select p.*, sumstock, minprice
from products p left outer join
     (select s.pid, sum(stock) as sumstock, min(price) as minprice
      from stock s
      group by s.pid
     ) sp
     on sp.pid = p.id
order by minprice
```

Comment: Hmm, wasn't clear whether current stock was for all suppliers or just the cheapest supplier, was it. Well one of us will be close.

Comment: You solution need sorting at the end, if I include that the query takes 12 seconds...

Comment: @user827910 . . . Ooops, I missed that in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem as follows, also adding an extra level where the current time is taken into account because some suppliers cannot deliver on time after a certain time of day. What I did not include is a sum(stock). I've added that field to the products table as sumStock and always update it whenever a stock record is changed.

```
SELECT    sp.price
,         p.*
FROM      products p 
LEFT JOIN stock_products sp
USING     (ean)
WHERE     sp.id = IFNULL(
          (SELECT    psi.id
           FROM      stock_products psi 
           JOIN      suppliers sup
           ON        psi.pid = sup.id
           WHERE     psi.ean = p.ean
           AND       psi.stock > 0
           ORDER BY  IF(sup.time>40667, sup.deliveryTime, sup.deliveryTime+86400)
           ,         price
           LIMIT 1)
          ,
          (SELECT    psi.id
           FROM      stock_products psi 
           JOIN      suppliers sup
           ON        psi.pid = sup.id
           WHERE     psi.ean = p.ean
           ORDER BY  IF(sup.time>40667, sup.deliveryTime, sup.deliveryTime+86400)
           ,         price
           LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY  price
```

Note that I use the IFNULL for the rare cases a product has no stock. I still want to show those records. The query is a bit shorter without, but this is the complete solution I ended up using.

Also, 40667 is a number representing the current time. It should be whatever the current number of seconds since midnight is.